# Error: expression must have pointer-to-class type

Tags: c++, pointers, queue

I am trying to implement queue using structs. Here is a struct itself:

```
struct Item
{
    datatype data;
    Item* next;
};
```

However, when I try to add a new element, I get an error:

```
void enqueue(Item** front, Item** rear, datatype D) { //add element to queue
    Item* temp;
    temp = new Item;
    temp->data = D;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (*front == NULL){ // if queue is empty, make temp the first element
        *front = temp;
    }
    else { // else add it to the end
        rear->next = temp; //error is here
        *rear = temp;
    }
}
```

I've tried doing something like this `(*rear)->next = temp;` but then next is staying NULL.

Could you please help to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the queue is empty, you only assign `front` but `rear` must also point at the same `Item`.

```
if (*front == nullptr){ // if queue is empty, make temp the first element
    *front = temp;
}
else { // else add it to the end
    (*rear)->next = temp;         // <- fix like this
}
*rear = temp;                     // <- do this in both cases
```

Otherwise the next object you `enqueue` will be using a `rear` that is pointing at what you initialized it with at start, probably `NULL`.